# Area of equilateral triangle from circumcircle

Tags: circles, triangles, area

I am trying to calculate skewness of triangle. Given the sides of a triangle (not equilateral), I calculated circumradius from which I would like to get area of equilateral triangle.

Comment: So you already have a radius?  The area of an equilateral triangle given the length from its circumcenter to a vertex is going to be $\frac 32 r\cdot r\over \sqrt 3$

Comment: @abiessu Could you show me a reference?

Comment: I don't have one off hand, that was just calculated from the formula for a triangle area together with the known ratios of the sides of an equilateral: $1:\sqrt 3:2$.  The radius you have is the "$2$" side in this case, and the remaining distance to the "base" from the circumcenter is the "$1$" side which is the $\frac 32r$ factor.  The base size is then the "$\sqrt 3$" side, although I divided when I should have multiplied.  The correct formula would be $\frac 32r\cdot \frac{\sqrt 3}2r$.